# Apply CSS to particular report in JasperReports Server

Tags: java, jasperserver

I tried applying css to individual report using **controls and resource** option with the name **overrides_custom.css** but the thing is this css is not getting reflected instead it is using the **default themes overrides_custom.css**. Hope that i will get the solution from you people soon. I am using *JasperReports Server Community Edition*.